# Crypto Key not Available - ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, mpeg-dash, exoplayer2.x

So I am trying to play an Encrypted Content in a Dash File(.mpd),packaged with Shaka Packager and encrypted with CENC Method. The media plays absolutely fine on Shaka Player, but I am unable to make it play on ExoPlayer in Android. On playing, the Logcat shows the following error :

```
Caused by: android.media.MediaCodec$CryptoException: Crypto key not available
    at android.media.MediaCodec.native_queueSecureInputBuffer(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaCodec.queueSecureInputBuffer(MediaCodec.java:2699)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.feedInputBuffer(MediaCodecRenderer.java:1188)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.render(MediaCodecRenderer.java:719) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:599) 
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:329) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

The Build.Gradle has Minimum Sdk limit at API 21, so that checks out, and the code used is :

```
    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
    ep.setPlayer(player);

    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "AppName"));
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Tools.baseAddress+"VIDEO/"+i.getStringExtra("ModuleID")+"/index.php").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("token", Tools.token).build();

    String keyString = "{\"keys\":[{\"kty\":\"oct\",\"k\":\"76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb\",\"kid\":\"a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8\"}],'type':\"temporary\"}";

    LocalMediaDrmCallback drmCallback = new LocalMediaDrmCallback(keyString.getBytes());
    DrmSessionManager manager=null;
    manager = new DefaultDrmSessionManager.Builder()
            .setPlayClearSamplesWithoutKeys(true)
            .setMultiSession(false)
            .setUuidAndExoMediaDrmProvider(C.CLEARKEY_UUID, FrameworkMediaDrm.DEFAULT_PROVIDER)
            .build(drmCallback);

    MediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).setDrmSessionManager(manager).createMediaSource(uri);

    player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

    ep.setPlayer(player);
    player.prepare(dashMediaSource);
```

And the command used while packaging the MP4 Video was using Shaka Packager was :

```
.\packager input=videoplayback.mp4,stream=video,output=video.mp4 input=videoplayback.mp4,stream=audio,output=audio.mp4 --enable_raw_key_encryption --keys key_id=a7e61c373e219033c21091fa607bf3b8:key=76a6c65c5ea762046bd749a2e632ccbb --clear_lead 0 --mpd_output dash.mpd
```

I am not sure if the key formation is correct or the DRM Session Manager is properly initialized.
I would be really grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the method LocalMediaDrmCallback is expecting the key and key_id to be in base64url encoding.

You can covert your key and key_id to this using an online tool such as:

- https://base64.guru/standards/base64url/encode

You can see a programatic example in this GitHub issue discussion also: https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3856#issuecomment-366197586

Answer (score 1):

I had spend long time to research "CryptoKey not available" Exception.

I found this exception happen with some wrong things.

1. The MediaDrmCallback is bad. When use ClearKey system, use LocalMediaDrmCallback or sub classes, CAN NOT with network.
2. The key response (kid & k) base64url implements bad, not include '/' '=' '\n' '+'
3. Some media file encrypt with clearlead time, My video set parameter is 30s so it always happen exception, I think Android DRM session or keys has timeout in memory.
4. DrmSessionManager configs set bad. pay attention with "setMultiSession" it will break your set.
5. I fix this excetion with:

   1. setMultiSession(true), true is for one req return one key, don't use "false"
   2. Replace and implement other MediaDrmCallback, implement "One Req return One key" with Map<String,String>

Reasons:

1. Some Devices or DRM session implements has timeout I think, If your video have clearlead time, and DRM will play clear content and encrypted content. When Video load start play and first encrypted content play, The DRM session will get Key twice. so the first key used can't load video load key.
2. When you DASH manifest file contains some videos with difference key, AUDIO, HD, SD or other, when Network speed low or high, the video which played will changed and DRM session will decrypt with other key, but i think change will can't find right key.
3. When I use setMultiSession(false) -> this mean "One request response All keys", and simple with LocalMediaDrmCallback(responseJson), my video will play error or good, I think some time device load json and find first key, or other time with bad key.

I had write some code and information this issue in my website: https://blackfire.mobi (Chinese), see it to fix this.

I think "CryptoKey not available" Exception is so bad and write this reply for you.